# Parallel image processing pipelines using Python and `multiprocessing`

Tags: python, image-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm designing an image processing pipeline that includes pyramid processing. In short, an input image is divided into several output images of different resolution (coarse, fine, etc). This decomposition allows performing different image processing tasks at different resolution scales.

I would like to know if it's possible in Python to spawn *e.g.* 3 child interpreters that each instantiate a different image processing pipeline. Then, when an input image is available, the parent process decomposes it into 3 different sub-images of different resolution scales. Each child process is given a sub-image and executes the tasks specified at the instantiation of the pipelines. Finally, when each sub-image has been processed, a final image is computed by the parent interpreter.

I'm not sure where to start with this, mostly because what I'd like to know is whether or not it is feasible.

Comment: You're asking about multiprocessing in the title, have you looked at all at the `multiprocessing` standard Python library? It sounds like you want most of the actual work to be done by third party tools and libraries, and it's likely that you don't need multiprocessing at all, but rather want to run these as asynchronous tasks. Both approaches can be done in Python - have a look at both, try something and ask specific questions about problems with your code on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have looked at `multiprocessing`. From my understanding, I can use it with callables but not to do what I described. I don't necessarily want the work to be done by a plug-and-play library, and because I need the outputs immediately it doesn't seem like asynchronous tasks are a good candidate. I was hoping for some literature suggestions. I'm not a SW engineer, just an ultrasound engineer who uses Python.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a literature review or recommendation site. If you have a look at some of the literature, and come up with a way to implement this, StackOverflow is the right place to ask about problems with getting it to work. You say asynchronous processing wouldn't suit because you need results immediately, but I strongly doubt that - you're not processing live video here, you need the results right after they're done, and async sounds just about right. Having said that, if there's some reason you must have streaming results, multiprocessing is the right choice.

Comment: If you were looking for recommendations for libraries or frameworks that do part of the work already though, that's definitely not what StackOverflow is for - again, find what you need and please feel free to come back with questions on how to get it to work if you have trouble.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write these messages, and I understand I need to look somewhere else for an answer. However you're assuming a lot here. I'm processing a live feed of images in real time to the tune of up to 60 frames per second. So again, I don't think asynchronous tasks are the way to go.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think you understand the differences between parallel processing and asynchronous processing - which is evidenced by your responses here. Part of getting a good answer is being open to learning something and changing your mind. The overhead of parallel processing is unlikely to make that the solution you need in Python - of course an asynchronous solution could still have independent workers running in parallel, there just doesn't seem to be any benefit to parallelising the work that needs to happen in Python itself.

Comment: You're right, the differences between these concepts are still fuzzy to me. However, I am here to learn, and I'm happy to have my mind changed. From what I've been reading so far, including your messages, I was leaning towards multiprocessing. You implied earlier that I would need this if I was processing live video and streaming results, and it resonated with me as desirable things for my application. But I need to spend more time understanding the fundamentals. As you suggested, I'll be back with more specific questions when I manage to put something together. Thanks again.